# JMS Client for WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5 and 7.0.0.13 with Oracle Java 8

Tags: jms, websphere, jndi, corba

I am using Java JMS client to connect to Websphere Application Server 8.5.5.0 and 7.0.0.13. I using following set of jars in classpath of client:
ibmorb.jar, ibmorbapi.jar, com.ibm.jaxws.thinclient_.jar, com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_.jar, com.ibm.ws.sib.client.thin.jms_.jar.

It works fine with Oracle Java 7. But with Oracle Java 8 it gives java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/io/MalformedInputException during JNDI lookup. The ibmorb.jar is using sun.io.MalformedInputException class which is no longer shipped with Java 8. I also tried using com.ibm.ws.orb_.jar in place of ibmorb.jar but got same exception.

What is the suggested approach to solve this problem?

I tried with ibmorb.jar from optional IBM Java Developer Kit 7 provided with 8.5.5.3 and it worked. I did not find standalone installer for IBM Java 7 and I don't want to upgrade the AppServer on server side. If using jars from IBM Java 7 is the only option then how can I get the standalone IBM Java 7 installer or IBM Java 7 for 7.0.0.13?

Comment: You might want to open a PMR with IBM since according to http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tjj_jmsthcli_dev.html Oracle (SUN) JREs above 1.5 are supported.

Comment: See some comments to this questions were posted on [wasdev.net](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/166621/jms-client-for-websphere-application-server-855-an.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can get IBM JDK from here - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/index.html